# Why Twig falls back to object when a property doesn't exist?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to print an object's property on my template:

```
{{ MyObject.itsProperty }}
```

The thing is, this property is not set, `__isset` will return `false` and `__get` will return `null`.

Instead of printing nothing and leave it at that, Twig tries to print MyObject which causes an error:

> Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class MyObject could not be
>   converted to string in
>   .....vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(378) : eval()'d code on
>   line 54

Setting `strict_variables` to `false` didn't help. How to deal with it?

Comment: I've never seen that behavior...as a hacky workaround you could define `__toString()` for the object and have it return an empty string...

Comment: Do you have a getItsProperty(), hasItsProperty() or isItsProperty() function implemented in MyObject class?

Comment: Have you tried `{{ MyObject.itsProperty|default('') }}`?

Comment: @GentlemanMax yes, but what should I do the day I need to implement toString for a real thing?

Comment: @Paulpro it results in the same Exception

Comment: @iiirxs no, I have __isset, also I wanted to avoid adding methods to either the object or twig. I want my templates to be clean and readable

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: @iiirxs I have it disabled actually

Comment: @Adinan, hence "hacky workaround". Does `MyObject` have a `__call()` method?  Twig will try that too when trying to resolve a dot operator.

Comment: @GentlemanMax ahaha.... as matter of fact it did... and returning $this .... that explains it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GentlemanMax pointed out, Twig will try calling methods as well as properties in attempt to resolve a dot operator.
Which may result in callings to the __get and __call magic methods.

My problem was my implementation of __call which was returning $this, resulting in the error I mention above.

Thank you @GentlemanMax and everybody else for helping me out.

Comment: Then how do you solve it? return `$this` is required for chain property calling